# Laravel ajax post method gives MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make an ajax POST request to a controller function but I keep getting this error. I followed the advice I found online and added `$.ajaxSetup` with `X-CSRF-TOKEN` but still no luck.

> "exception":
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

**web.php**

```
Route::get('my-controller/mypostfunction', 'MyController@mypostfunction');
```

**MyController.php**

```
public function mypostfunction()
{
    return "Hello poster!";
}
```

**app.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
          $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

          // This alerts the CSRF token correctly!
          alert( $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') );

    $.post( "my-controller/mypostfunction", function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your web.php file u set get method so just change `get` to `post` method type

```
Route::post('my-controller/mypostfunction', 'MyController@mypostfunction');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **web.php** change route for **get** to **post** like this:

```
Route::get('my-controller/mypostfunction', 'MyController@mypostfunction');

// into 

Route::post('my-controller/mypostfunction', 'MyController@mypostfunction');
```

I hope this is the solution.